# Differentiability of distance function

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $K= [0,1] \backslash (1/3, 2/3).$ For $x \in [0,1],$ define $f(x)= d(x,K)= \inf\{|x-y| : y \in K\}.$ Then

1. $f: [0,1] \to \mathrm{R} $ is differentiable at all points of $(0,1).$
2. $f: [0,1] \to \mathrm{R} $ is not differentiable at $1/3$ and $2/3.$
3. $f: [0,1] \to \mathrm{R} $ is not differentiable at $1/2.$
4. $f$ is not continuous.

$4.$ is false since $f$ is continuous and $f(x)= 0$ for $ x \in [0,1/3] \cup [2/3,1]$, but unable to find value of $f(x)$, when $x \in (1/3, 2/3)$. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=x-\frac 1 3$ when $x \leq \frac 1 2$ and $f(x)=\frac  2 3-x$ when $\frac  1 2 \leq x <\frac 2 3$.

[You only have to see which of the numbers $|x-\frac 1 3|$ and $|x-\frac 2 3|$ is smaller. The answer depends on whether $x \leq \frac 1 2$ or $x > \frac 1 2$].

Comment: Thank you for valuable answer